# Contact form in ruby, sinatra, and haml

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml, pony

I'm new to all three, and I'm trying to write a simple contact form for a website.  The code I have come up with is below, but I know there are some fundamental problems with it (due to my inexperience with sinatra).  Any help at getting this working would be appreciated, I can't seem to figure out/find the documentation for this sort of thing.

haml code from the contact page:

```
%form{:name => "email", :id => "email", :action => "/contact", :method => "post", :enctype => "text/plain"}
  %fieldset
    %ol
      %li
        %label{:for => "message[name]"} Name:
        %input{:type => "text", :name => "message[name]", :class => "text"}
      %li
        %label{:for => "message[mail]"} Mail:
        %input{:type => "text", :name => "message[mail]", :class => "text"}
      %li
        %label{:for => "message[body]"} Message:
        %textarea{:name => "message[body]"}
    %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Send", :class => "button"}
```

And here is my code in sinatra's app.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'
require 'pony'

    get '/' do
        haml :index
    end 

    get '/contact' do
        haml :contact
    end

    post '/contact' do
        name = #{params[:name]}
        mail = #{params[:mail]}
        body = #{params[:body]}     
        Pony.mail(:to => '*emailaddress*', :from => mail, :subject => 'art inquiry from' + name, :body => body) 
    end
```

Comment: Where's the `get` and what error do you get?
Also, what's up with the message[mail] naming? Why not just "mail"?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I figured it out for any of you wondering:

haml:

```
%form{ :action => "", :method => "post"}
  %fieldset
    %ol
      %li
        %label{:for => "name"} Name:
        %input{:type => "text", :name => "name", :class => "text"}
      %li
        %label{:for => "mail"} email:
        %input{:type => "text", :name => "mail", :class => "text"}
      %li
        %label{:for => "body"} Message:
        %textarea{:name => "body"}
    %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Send", :class => "button"}
```

And the app.rb:

```
post '/contact' do
        name = params[:name]
        mail = params[:mail]
        body = params[:body]

        Pony.mail(:to => '*emailaddress*', :from => "#{mail}", :subject => "art inquiry from #{name}", :body => "#{body}")

        haml :contact
    end
```

Comment: Little error in this response about the 'for' attribute in labels:
"This attribute explicitly associates the label being defined with another control. When present, the value of this attribute must be the same as the value of the id attribute of some other control in the same document. When absent, the label being defined is associated with the element's contents." — http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone can use this, here is what you might need to use your gmail account to send mail.

```
post '/contact' do 
require 'pony'
Pony.mail(
   :name => params[:name],
  :mail => params[:mail],
  :body => params[:body],
  :to => 'a_lumbee@gmail.com',
  :subject => params[:name] + " has contacted you",
  :body => params[:message],
  :port => '587',
  :via => :smtp,
  :via_options => { 
    :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com', 
    :port                 => '587', 
    :enable_starttls_auto => true, 
    :user_name            => 'lumbee', 
    :password             => 'p@55w0rd', 
    :authentication       => :plain, 
    :domain               => 'localhost.localdomain'
  })
redirect '/success' 
end
```

Note the redirect at the end, so you will need a success.haml to indicate to the user that their email was sent successfully.

Comment: In case anyone is using this, the upper `:port => '587'` declaration caused an error (the lower under `:via_options => {` is valid, though).

Answer (score 5):

Uhmm, i tried in irb the following:

```
foo = #{23}
```

Of course it wont work! the '#' is for comments in Ruby UNLESS it occurs in a string! Its even commented out in the syntax highlighting.
What you wanted was:

```
name = "#{params[:name]}"
```

as you did in your solution (which is not necessary, as it already is a string).

Btw, the reason why the code does not throw an error is the following:

```
a =
b =
42
```

will set a and b to 42. You can even do some strange things (as you accidentally did) and set the variables to the return value of a function which takes these variables as parameters:

```
def foo(a,b)
    puts "#{a.nil?} #{b.nil?}" #outputs 'true true'
    return 42
end
a =
b =
foo(a,b)
```

will set a and b to 42.

Answer (score 2):

#{} is interpolation that is used inside "". Just using it outside for a variable assignment won't work.

It would be more likely to be used like this:

```
number_of_people = 15 

Puts "There are #{number_of_people} scheduled tonight"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created an example of this in two parts that is available on github. The signup form app is here: [signup-form-heroku](https://github.com/nogeek/signup-form-heroku) and an example of the static website that interacts with this is here: [static-website-to-s3-example](https://github.com/nogeek/static-website-to-s3-example).
The form app is built using Sinatra and is ready to deploy straight onto Heroku. The static site is ready to deploy straight to S3 and use amazon cloudfront.