# Getting Ruby contact form working with Pony, Sinatra and Middleman

Tags: ruby, forms, sinatra, middleman, pony

I'm creating a contact page with the usual form, and I found Pony which seemed to fit the bill for what I needed. The site is basically static, so is built using Middleman, but I've been reading around and figured to add a contact form Sinatra would be helpful.

I have my form; I have my ruby code, but I'm having difficulty pulling them together. I seem to be missing something that will trigger the ruby code.

The form, in /source/contact-us.html.haml :

```
    %form.contact{ :action => "/contact-us.html", :method => "post"}
      %fieldset

        %label{:for => "name"} Full name *
        %input{:type => "text", :name => "name"}

        %label{:for => "email"} Email addresss *
        %input{:type => "text", :name => "email"}

        %label{:for => "phone"} Phone *
        %input{:type => "text", :name => "phone"}

        %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Send", :class => "read-more"}
```

And the ruby code (currently in /mail.rb) :

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'pony'

post '/contact-us.html' do
  options = {
    :to => '[my email]',
    :from => params[:email],
    :subject => params[:name],
    :body => params[:phone]
  }

  Pony.mail(options)

  redirect '/thankyou.html'
end
```

I'm testing things out both locally and hosted on a server that I've verified is running Ruby (which is always a good start ;) )

I've had a look elsewhere on stackoverflow and I found things like these, but nothing that helped me solve my problem :

[Contact form in ruby, sinatra, and haml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068148/contact-form-in-ruby-sinatra-and-haml)

[Sending mail with Pony and Sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709421/sending-mail-with-pony-and-sinatra)

This is the first time I'm using Ruby and Middleman for a site, so I'm learning lots - I can't help but feel that I've missed something fairly obvious here..

Comment: try params['email'] (not params[:email]), params['name'], params['phone']

Comment: Hmm, just tried that, and it doesn't seem to have changed anything. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: Could you specify which part doesn't work? Does the route get the request?